# Breakpoints in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, breakpoints

I'm attempting add a breakpoint in eclipse but its not working.  I right click on the margin on the jsp file and select add breakpoint but nothing happens.

Have you seen this before?

Comment: Need more info. What plug-ins are you using and for what language?

Comment: Just a thing to note, that I learned recently: You can only add breakpoints to `expressions`. Can't assign breakpoint to function declarations like eg. `public void run()` or to blank lines. For variable declaration lines you can only add watchpoints , not breakpoints.

Comment: i'm programming in java.  writing and google appengine hosted mobile app.

Comment: i can add breakpoints in .java files, but not .jsp files

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the follwoing:

1. Project -> Clean.
2. Then try to add the break point.
3. If not successfull, try to restart the eclipse.
4. Try alsp to double click the margin to add break point.
5. Try pressing these buttons together: cnrl + shift + b.
6. Select 'Run' and toggle breakpoint.

Hope this helps

Comment: i tried all the above and still no luck

Comment: Doesnt work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53915010/breakpoints-not-working-on-jsp-pages-in-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

You have to double click on the gutter of the editor to toggle the breakpoint. Take a look at the official documentation [here](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-add_line_breakpoints.htm?cp=1_3_6_0_0) .

Comment: Doesnt work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53915010/breakpoints-not-working-on-jsp-pages-in-eclipse

Answer (score -1):

In `jsp` file you can set breakpoint only where you have `java` section  , like  - `${....}`

Comment: i'm trying to do it in the java section marked by <% %>

Comment: Doesnt work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53915010/breakpoints-not-working-on-jsp-pages-in-eclipse