# Breakpoints not working on JSP pages in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, websphere, websphere-8

Breakpoints are being hit in the Java code, the project is being run as Debug, "Skip All Breakpoints" is disabled, line breakpoints (blue dots) are on lines in my JSP pages.

[image: JSP page with breakpoint]

The result in the web browser debug, so I know it's hitting the right page:
[image: Web browser]

Why are my breakpoints on JSP pages not being hit? I'm having no issue making changes and seeing them reflected in the browser. Eclipse 4.6.2. WebSphere 8.5

**Edit**: I'm not sure if this is related. When I try to start my server in Eclipse it says

> Cannot connect to the server process. Make sure the server is already started.

to get it to start in Eclipse I have to double click the server and uncheck:

> Start a server with a generated script

Comment: probably, code is not same on server and IDE

Comment: Which server and Java Runtime are you using? Some don't actually support debugging. Do you also have automatic builds enabled? It's used to automatically deploy and redeploy files.

Comment: The "aaaaa" was a different text before and I'm able to update it. I'm having no issue making changes. "Build Automatically" is enabled. I'm using WebSphere 8.5 Full

Comment: Thats weird, if both your project and your server are running in debug mode, shouldnt skip breakpoints... re-check your server is also running in debug mode.

Comment: Breakpoints hit on Java files. So i think they're both in debug mode. I'm still having this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a workaround. In the JSP, import a Java class and call one of it's methods. Put a breakpoint at the end of that method and step through it (F5) into the JSP.

Answer (score 0):

It's very related. When Eclipse itself launches the actual Java command that runs the server, it is includes JVM arguments to setup debug communication with the Java process and installs all if the set breakpoints. If it did not, it basically attaches to the server process as a generic Java application--which does not attempt to install all of the breakpoints in the workspace. Instead, you need to create (or enable) breakpoints after having connected to the process for them to be installed properly.

Answer (score -1):

To get debug on a JSP you might need an additional step:

Open the appropriate server in the Servers view of the Server Perspective (Window > Open Perspective > Server), and ensure that the Generate debug information when compiling JSPs (debug mode only) check box is selected.  Close the server editor.

This is described in this doc:  [Debugging JSP files](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHR6W/com.ibm.websphere.wdt.doc/topics/tdbgjsp.html)

Comment: There is no Server perspective in Eclipse (4.6.2).